# Can someone please break this code down and explain it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem is: Given an array of numbers, check if any of the numbers are the character codes for lower case vowels (a, e, i, o, u).

*Here is where I am curious...*

**This:**

```
def is_vow(inp):
    for key, val in enumerate(inp):
        if chr(val) in 'aeiou':
            inp[key] = chr(val)
    return inp
```

**Does the same thing as this: (Which is what I wrote)**

```
def is_vow(inp):
    lst1 = []
    for vow in inp:
        if vow == 97:
            lst1.append('a')
        elif vow == 101:
            lst1.append('e')
        elif vow == 105:
            lst1.append('i')
        elif vow == 111:
            lst1.append('o')
        elif vow == 117:
            lst1.append('u')
        else:
            lst1.append(vow)
    return lst1
```

I get that the first solution will enumerate through the parameter 'inp' and checks to see if the character is in 'aeiou', I just don't get how it returns the correct values...

I just want to understand it so I can learn how to shorten my code and not have to repeat myself.

P.S. - I'm still new to the Python language.

Comment: `97` is the ASCII code for the character `a` (same as `65` is the ASCII code for the character `A`). [See also the Wikipedia article on ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), which, for most purposes, is how simple characters (the ones you'd find on your keyboard) are encoded. The `chr()` method in python will convert an ASCII code to the corresponding character, and the `ord()` method will do the reverse. For example, `chr(97) -> 'a'` and `ord('a') -> 97`.

Comment: (note that python actually uses Unicode for encoding strings, but for all characters that exist in both encodings, the ASCII code is the same as the Unicode code)

Comment: They don't do the same thing. The first version modifies the input list in place, the second version creates a new list.

Comment: Ahhh! Okay, I understand that now. I wasn't sure because I got the same output, but I was doing extra steps that weren't needed. Thank you! Also I didn't know about those 2 methods 'chr()' and 'ord()'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
inp = [97, 99, ...]
for i, val in enumerate(inp):
```

Step through the input list, keeping an index (I renamed `i`).

```
if chr(val) in 'aeiou':
```

Parse the number as ascii (`chr()`) and then see if it's one of `aeiou`.  Remember strings are iterable in python.  (`chr()` is the magic here you probably didn't expect; try it out in a repl).

```
inp[i] = chr(val)
```

Replace the current element in the original list with its ascii equivalent.  Notice that we call `chr` twice!  This would be more efficient:

```
c = chr(val)
if c in "aeiou":
    inp[i] = c
```

You can also write that with the dreaded walrus operator, but I leave that as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot! I'll have to look into the 'walrus' operator.

Comment: @michaelcronk [see the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/).  It would let you save one line here (the `c=chr(val)`) at the cost of syntax which... well, _de gustibus non est disputandum_

Comment: I'll be looking into it more, thanks again!